# Get shortest path between two objects based on their relations

Tags: c#, sql, sorting

I am trying to figure out the best way in either SQL or C# to solve this.
Lets say i have a list of about 50 or so objects, each of them relates to two other objects.

```
Object 1.
ID: 1
Name:      Aspect1
Relation1: Aspect5
Relation2: Aspect7

Object 2.
ID:    2
Name:      Aspect2
Relation1: Aspect23
Relation2: Aspect50

Object 3
ID:   13
Name:      Aspect13
Relation1: Aspect5
Relation2: Aspect23
```

basically i need to look at all 50 objects and then find the shortest path to connect aspect1 to aspect2 by connecting them through other aspects with a minimum of 3 connections in between them.

the end result would look something like

```
aspect1 -- aspect5 -- aspect13 -- aspect23 -- aspect2
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff, why so hard?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Yes, but to part of provided issues here you have answered in your post bellow (the few count of vertexes, fixed count of junction), form another hand there is the [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm#Algorithm).

Comment: @HamletHakobyan . . . I'm was thinking of the shortest path visiting all the vertices, not connecting two of them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, What do you mean?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan It sounds like he was reading it as a traveling salesman problem rather than a shortest path problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL is not optimized for this sort of problem.  However, you can run successive queries to try out paths of length 4, 5, and so on:

```
with relations as (
      select objectid as from_o, relation1 as to_o
      from objects
      union all
      select objectid, relation2
      from objects
     )
select *
from relations r1 join
     relations r2
     on r1.to_o = r2.from_o join
     relations r3
     on r2.to_o = r3.from_o join
     relations r4
     on r3.to_o = r4.from_o
where r1.objectid = 'Aspect1' and
      r4.objectid = 'Aspect2';
```

With only two relationships per object and 50 objects, this should be a solvable problem for shortish paths.  If this query doesn't return anything, you would continue adding joins in a similar fashion.  If your database doesn't support `with`, you can use either subqueries or views to achieve the same effect.

There is a method using recursive CTEs to solve this.  However, you don't specify the database, and not all databases support them.

Comment: @beefwipe . . . If you want to be sure that shorter paths don't interfere, then add `r2.objectid <> 'Aspect2' and r3.objectid <> 'Aspect3'` to the `where` clause.